# I want to update the string data which has double quotes and semicolon in it

Tags: java, collections, stream

```
import java.util.*;

class ChangeCSS{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter the Code to be converted to red css");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner("System.in");
    String str=sc.nextLine();

    //Entered by user String str="<p style="text-align: center;">. <span class="text__white">Techno power</span></p>";
  }
}
```

User inputs the above string

I am trying to update text__white to text__red

But inputing the above string in any String object is popping error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Put  string into single quotes, this will allow yuo to use double quotes unescaped. Before any other character you have to put "\" backslash, to mark it being part of the string.

Comment: @JustInCoding illegal start of exception and at semicolon after the center

Comment: @AndrejJurkin Java does not support single quotes for strings; that would be javascript.

Comment: @AndrejJurkin can u provide some example..I am new to the java. User inputs the above string and I want to replace text__white to text__red

Comment: Then, you can refer to the answer given below by @KomalSinghSisodiya

Answer (score 3):

You can use front slash in front of every special char
like below-

```
String str="<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span class=\"text__white\">Techno power</span></p>";
```

Comment: the above string is inputted by user

Comment: @Ronnie Does that mean a user will have access to your source code or order to modify it, recompile it and then run it? Or is there some additional functionality you have not shown us?

Comment: it should be formatted if coming from the user, take input from the user and print it to see.

Answer (score 1):

I know the above answer corrects your String, but here's how you can replace the word `text__white` with `text__red` using the `String.replace(String str1, String str2)` method:

```java
public class ReplaceString {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span class=\"text__white\">Techno power</span></p>";
    String strrep = str.replace("text__white", "text__red");
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(strrep);
  }
}
```

You can implement the required logic in your code from here.

Comment: You don't need to use `replaceAll` as you aren't using a significant regular expression. Just use `str.replace("text__white", "text__red")` to avoid overhead of regex.